# SQL: Get posts made by friends

Tags: sql, join

I want to write a query to retrieve all posts written by friends I have on an app.

My table structure is:

```
Entity:
---------------------
EntityID  -  PK
FirstName -  VARCHAR
LastName  -  VARCHAR

Friends:
---------------------
FriendID  - PK
Friend1   - INT
Friend2   - INT

Post:
---------------------
PostID    - PK
EntityId  - INT
Message   - VARCHAR
```

The above schema has been simplified to demo the structure.

So far I have tried the following, but it will only retrieve posts made by the user with the ID `5`.  How can I make the query return posts by this user and all of his/her friends?

```
SELECT 
   P.PostID,
   P.Message,
   E.FirstName,
   E.LastName,
FROM 
   Entity AS E
JOIN 
   Friends AS F
      ON (E.EntityId = F.Friend1 OR E.EntityId = F.Friend2)
INNER JOIN
   Posts AS P
      ON P.EntityId = F.Friend1 OR P.Entity_Id = F.Friend2
WHERE 
   E.EntityId = 5
ORDER BY
   P.PostID DESC
```

If I had the data set:

```
FriendId   |   Friend1   |   Friend2  |
    1             8             5
    2             9             5
    3             5             3
    4             2             4


PostId     |  EntityId  |  Message
    1             5           Hello
    2             8           Goodbye
    3             2           Morning
```

I would expect only `hello` and `goodbye` to be returned as the user id of `2` has no connection to 5, but all of 5s posts should be returned.  I've been staring at this for  awhile and cant seem to fathom it.

Comment: You're ignoring the Relation column. If that's intentional, omit it from the question

Comment: My appologies, yes the relation column only filters out blocked users.

Comment: Did you find the reason your query didn't work?

Comment: I'm thinking my test data may have been slightly wrong

Comment: So other than the fact you got a different method to construct your query, there isn't anything you need(ed)?

Comment: That is correct, Tim's method stated below worked fine - thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically , you need only a simple query to get posts matching your criteria:

```
select * from post
where entityid in (select friend1 from friends where friend2 = 5 )
or entityid in (select friend2 from friends where friend1 =5)
or entityid = 5;
```

Then add the stuffs you need:

```
select p.postid, e.lastname,e.firstname,e.entityid , p.message from post p
join entity e on e.entityid=p.entityid    
where p.entityid in (select friend1 from friends where friend2 = 5 )
or p.entityid in (select friend2 from friends where friend1 =5)
or p.entityid = 5;
```

And now change it to a join version:

```
select p.postid, e.lastname,e.firstname,e.entityid , p.message from post p
join (
    select friend1 from friends where friend2 =5 
    union select friend2 from friends where friend1 =5 
    union select 5 from dual) m
on p.entityid = m.friend1 
join entity e 
on p.entityid=e.entityid;
```

Comment: This works perfectly - banging my head on the wall for overthinking it!  Thanks.

Comment: I usually use IN to make things easier before I do any optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  p.postid
  ,p.message
  ,e.firstname
  ,e.lastname
FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN entity e
  ON e.entityid = p.entityid
WHERE e.entityid IN (
  SELECT friend2
  FROM friends 
  WHERE friend1 = 5

  UNION 

  SELECT friend1 
  FROM friends 
  WHERE friend2 = 5    
)
```

returns:

```
postid    message    firstname    lastname
2         Goodbye    John8        Doe8
```

The post "hello" is not returned since its author is not a friend of user 5, but user 5 himself.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2ea7/5)